# How do vampires cover themselves with dirt?

Tags: true-blood

In *True Blood* (and presumably *The Southern Vampire Mysteries*) a vampire will occasionally "go to ground". Or ,alternately, when they turn someone they bury themselves underground.  Whenever the burying part is shown though, we see someone else burying them.  How would a vampire "go to ground" without someone else there to shovel the dirt on top of them?  Or are we supposed to believe that the pull a Scrooge McDuck through the dirt?

Comment: Step 1. Dig a grave, shovel the dirt on a blanket beside the grave. Step 2. Lay down in the grave. Step 3. Pull the blanket with the dirt on it over you. WARNING: Don't try this at home!

Comment: http://media.rob.nu/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/whattheawwyeahp1.gif

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Of course I've covered myself in dirt -- but not 3 feet down.  They don't have the armlength to pile the dirt on top of themselves down there, nor do I see anyway in which they could make it look like relatively undisturbed ground (like when Sookie walked on top of the ground where Bill was resting just as he was climbing out).

Comment: @Einer Clever, but I highly doubt that'll look like flat ground.  It'll either be too shallow -- with bits of dirt all around where you want it -- or more likely too high -- because now you're taking up some of the space underground where the dirt was -- and would then not be a good hiding place because anyone that was aware that vampires sometimes sleep in the ground would be able to find them fairly easily (if they knew roughly where the vampire might have buried themselves).

Comment: @user31060 True, but those problems will arise too, if someone else buries you. You can always spot a fresh grave. And if you are specifically looking for a buried vampire, there will always be sings that will tip you off (no tombstone, tombstone but with old date but fresh grave...) It's never perfect. "Life" as a vampire is inherently dangerous!

Answer (score -2):

***I am going to go with Vampire magic. There is a similar thing in the Vampire The Masquerade Role playing game published by White Wolf called "Earth Meld". It is under the power "Protean". Here is an entry. http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Protean_(VTM)***